# Subtypes of Julia concrete types

Tags: julia

In order to practising with Julia, I am implementing a little module containing some fixed step ODE solvers (Euler, Runge Kutta, Bulirsch Stoer) using the iterator interface.

My idea was to use multiple dispatch to apply the correct method of the function `next` to the particular iterator, however the Euler and Runge Kutta iterator type (actually `immutable`) old the same data.

So I have to choose between:

1. create two `immutable` type identical except for the name or
2. crate a unique `immutable` with an additional field (say `solving_method`) and use branching instead of multiple dispatch to address this issue

Both choices seem clunky to me (in particular the second, because the `solving_method` field is checked at every iteration).

Reading the online discussions about inheritance in Julia I understood that Julia does not have (and will never have) subtypes of concrete types, meaning that one cannot "*add fields*" to a parent type in this way.

But why I cannot have subtypes of concrete types just for dispatching purposes?

Answer (score 2):

One idiomatic way to solve this flavor of problem is to create a type that stores parameters or the state of the solver and then have a second immutable to specify the method:

```
type SolverOptions
    # ... step size, error tol, etc.
end

immutable RungeKutta end

immutable Euler end

function solve(problem::ODE, method::RungeKutta, options::SolverOptions)
    # ... code here ...
end

function solve(problem::ODE, method::Euler, options::SolverOptions)
    # ... code here ...
end
```

Of course, RungeKutta and Euler need not be empty if you want to store some data in there. This isn't always the best solution (and I can't be sure that it will work in your particular case) but it can help when you are trying to prevent duplication of fieldnames.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try parametric types?

```
abstract OdeType
abstract Euler <: OdeType
abstract RK4 <: OdeType

immutable Common{T<:OdeType}
    x::Int
end
```